# Pre-processing images with convolutional layers in Tensorflow.js

Tags: machine-learning, keras, tensorflow.js

I'm trying to pre-process some images to feed into a VGG19-based model I trained offline. I tried to recreate the convolutional layers to process the image the same way the training set was, but I'm not sure how to pass the image through these convolutional layers on the one side and then use the input on my model.

Here's what I have so far:

```
<html>
<body>

<img id="imgcanvas" width="300" height="300" src='testimage1.jpg'></img>

</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
async function run(){

  const image = tf.browser.fromPixels(imgcanvas);
  const ModelImage = tf.sequential({
    layers: [tf.layers.conv2d({inputShape: [300, 300, 3], kernelSize: (3,3),
  filters: 64,
  padding: 'same',
  activation: 'relu'}),
  tf.layers.conv2d({ kernelSize: (3,3),
filters: 64,
padding: 'same',
activation: 'relu'}),
tf.layers.maxPooling2d({ poolSize: (2,2),
strides: (2,2)}),
tf.layers.conv2d({ kernelSize: (3,3),
filters: 128,
padding: 'same',
activation: 'relu'}),
tf.layers.conv2d({ kernelSize: (3,3),
filters: 128,
padding: 'same',
activation: 'relu'}),
tf.layers.maxPooling2d({ poolSize: (2,2),
strides: (2,2)}),
tf.layers.conv2d({ kernelSize: (3,3),
filters: 256,
padding: 'same',
activation: 'relu'}),
tf.layers.conv2d({ kernelSize: (3,3),
filters: 256,
padding: 'same',
activation: 'relu'}),
tf.layers.conv2d({ kernelSize: (3,3),
filters: 256,
padding: 'same',
activation: 'relu'}),
tf.layers.maxPooling2d({ poolSize: (2,2),
strides: (2,2)}),
tf.layers.conv2d({ kernelSize: (3,3),
filters: 512,
padding: 'same',
activation: 'relu'}),
tf.layers.conv2d({ kernelSize: (3,3),
filters: 512,
padding: 'same',
activation: 'relu'}),
tf.layers.conv2d({ kernelSize: (3,3),
filters: 512,
padding: 'same',
activation: 'relu'}),
tf.layers.maxPooling2d({ poolSize: (2,2),
strides: (2,2)}),
tf.layers.conv2d({ kernelSize: (3,3),
filters: 512,
padding: 'same',
activation: 'relu'}),
tf.layers.conv2d({ kernelSize: (3,3),
filters: 512,
padding: 'same',
activation: 'relu'}),
tf.layers.conv2d({ kernelSize: (3,3),
filters: 512,
padding: 'same',
activation: 'relu'}),
tf.layers.maxPooling2d({ poolSize: (2,2),
strides: (2,2)}),
           ]
  })
  const predict_image = ModelImage(image);
  const MODEL_URL = 'web_model/model.json';
  const model = await tf.loadGraphModel(MODEL_URL);
  const result = model.predict(predict_Image);
  result.print();
}
run();
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Why the `python` tag`?

Comment: The model was trained using python .... probably not necessary to this subject though